# What are good books about monopolies and market failures?

Tags: reference-request, monopoly

Is there a good undergraduate level book specifically about economic monopolies and market failures?

Comment: History or theory?

Comment: A standard reference, not undergrad though: Tirole, _Industrial Organization_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is quite broad in the sense that various forms of market failure cover a significant portion of all of microeconomics. I presume you have already looked in a general undergraduate micro book such as Varian's *[Intermediate Microeconmics](http://books.wwnorton.com/books/webad.aspx?id=4294979440)*, which provide coverage of many of these topics.

More detailed coverage of market power and monopoly can be found in Church and Ware's *[Industrial Organization: A Strategic Approach](http://works.bepress.com/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1022&context=jeffrey_church)*. Discussion of market failures caused by public goods and externalities can be found in  Hindriks and Myles' *[Intermediate Public Economics](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/intermediate-public-economics)*. For market failoures originating in information asymmetries, a good source might be Bolton and Dewatripont's *[Contract Theory](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/contract-theory)*.

Answer (score 3):

For advanced undergraduate students there is a nice, instructive and short book on [The Microeconomics of Market Failures](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/microeconomics-market-failures) at MIT Press (2000) by [Bernard Salanié](http://www.columbia.edu/~bs2237/) from Columbia.

The second revision of [Introduction to Industrial Organization](http://luiscabral.net/economics/books/iio2/) by [Luis Cabral](http://luiscabral.net/economics/) from NYU is a very good reference for undergraduates. The chapter 5 deals with Market Failure and Public Policy. Accompanying slides are available.

Answer (score 2):

"**The Economics of Imperfect Competition**" by Joan Robinson is a very old book, but one of the first to look specifically at market power. (By old, I mean like 1930s old). For something a little newer, you could try taking a look at some price theory books, like "**Price Theory and Its Uses**" by Watson and Getz.