# Textbook for industrial organization without calculus

Tags: industrial-organisation

I'm planning to teach an undergraduate course in industrial organization. Calculus is not a prerequisite. I also want to avoid doing too much game theory in it so as to not be duplicative of a similar course offering in game theory. Any recommendations on textbooks?

Answer (score 3):

Luis M Cabral : Introduction to Industrial Organization :- This book has a combo of game-theory and Cost curves. It explains strategic concepts using no calculus.
However, if you want more theoretical perspective , I would suggest reading the research papers (I have a course named Strategy , most of my readings are the journal papers on JSTOR or elsewhere).

If you could just expand on what your course comprises of , etc ;  or give a link to the university website , may be I can tell you more books I know of.

Comment: Here is the link to Cabral's book and other references https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9339/what-are-good-books-about-monopolies-and-market-failures/9360#9360

Comment: To be honest , the books you buy depends a lot on "what's on the table". It means what has been the testing and examination pattern of this course. What are the main reading texts for this course ( which the prof definitely uses himself).In crux , you better ask someone enrolled in the course.

Comment: For you studies , it's highly recommended you get hold of two to maximum three books only. From my own experience as an economics major ,it's much beneficial to focus on the examination/ testing pattern which has been prevalent in the respective institution.

Comment: @Vulcanwarrior96 My question was unclear, I suppose -- sorry! I'm planning on _teaching_ a class and was interested in suggestions for textbooks. I gather you were a student in a class that used Cabral. What are your impressions of Cabral?

Comment: It's a quantitative book. Starting with the definition of Industrial Organisation he expands on to explaining "what is a firm?".

Comment: He then goes on to explain collision , monopoly , different types of firm in the market. He then moves on to define market structure and market power. Further on he explains strategic behaviour of firms - product differentiation , advertising , r&d , network , etc.                               Practical examples have been mentioned again and again , not much but not few either.  It does use mathematics and very little calculus ( he never goes ahead of differentiating once ).